# Blackberry Design with custom button

Tags: blackberry

I am very new to blackberry development i want to know how can we design custom buttons and textfields and also set the position according to what we want?
can anyone explain it nicely?

Comment: Are you developing for BBOS or BB10 (Java or C++).  I presume Java, if so, have you looked at this: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276